# Remove crossed line - but on the next day

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

My script removes crossed lines - unfortunately the moment they get crossed.
Is there a way to keep that line for the remaining day/remove on start of new day?

...

```
    bool  lineCrossed =  high >= lineLevel and low <= lineLevel

    if lineCrossed                                              
        line.delete(array.get(_line,i))
```

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping the logic into following does the trick.

```
isToday = false

if year(timenow) == year(time) and month(timenow) == month(time) and dayofmonth(timenow) == dayofmonth(time)
    isToday := true
```

This allow to do something like this

```
bool  lineCrossed =  high >= lineLevel and low <= lineLevel

if lineCrossed
    if isToday
        doThis
    else                                      
        line.delete(array.get(_line,i))
```

('isToday' was provided by @Pugazh as solution to a previous issue he raised)